# Kann ein Relativsatz an ein Pronominaladverb angeschlossen werden?

Tags: relative-clause, pronominal-adverb

Welcher Satz ist hier der richtige?

> 1. a) Sie ist erstaunt darüber, was er gerade erzählt hat.
>      b) Sie ist erstaunt über das, was er gerade erzählt hat.
> 2. a) Ich konzentriere mich darauf, was vorgetragen wird.
>      b) Ich konzentriere mich auf das, was vorgetragen wird.
> 3. a) Denken wir daran, was ... gesagt hat.
>      b) Denken wir an das, was ... gesagt hat.

Comment: Zumindest 1a kann man auch ganz anders deuten (er hat erzählt, daß sie erstaunt ist).

Comment: Gefunden bei der Google-Suche, die Emanuel verlinkt hat: "Theoretiker streiten darüber, was wissenschaftlich ist." Tauscht man "darüber" mit "über das" aus, hat der Satz eine ganz andere Bedeutung.

Comment: @Em1: Am sichersten wäre wohl _streiten über die Frage, was wissenschaftlich ist_. Allerdings geht es am Thema vorbei, weil es sich um einen indirekten Fragesatz handelt, nicht um einen Relativsatz.

Comment: @chirlu... Em1s Beispiel ist relativ klar in Bezug auf indirekte Frage. Aber wie ist es mit "Das ist abhängig davon, was du essen willst." Man kann das als "abhängig von der Antwort auf die Frage, was..." interpretieren, wenn man will, aber das kann ich mit auf mit 1 machen. "Ich bin erstaunt über die Antwort auf die Frage was er gerade erzählt hat." Wie will man das gegeneinander abgrenzen. Und wieso ist "Unabhängig von dem, was..." nicht so idiomatisch wie "unabhängig davon,... "? Vielleicht sollte ich da mal 'ne Frage draus machen.

Comment: related: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/24864/abgrenzung-zwischen-was-als-relativ-und-als-fragepronomen

Answer (score 6):

In allen drei Fällen ist b) der richtige Satz.

[Cannoo](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Pronomen/PronAdv/Funktion.html): "Pronominaladverbien sind in der Regel nicht Bezugswort für einen attributiven Relativsatz. An ein Pronominaladverb kann in der Regel kein Relativsatz angeschlossen werden. Statt des Pronominaladverbs steht die Verbindung Präposition + Pronomen."

Eine schöne Erklärung kann ich leider nicht mitliefern. In meinen Ohren klingt die Variante a) jeweils zwar bekannt, aber nicht richtig.

Comment: @Emanuel: Gleicher Hinweis wie an Em1 oben, _was_ ist nicht nur Relativpronomen, sondern auch Interrogativpronomen; daher fängst du mit einer solchen Suche vor allem indirekte Fragesätze. Das ist auch ein Problem der Frage; ein eindeutiges Relativpronomen würde sofort erkennbar machen, daß _Ich konzentriere mich darauf, das vorgetragen wird_ nicht geht.

Comment: Was ist mit Formulierungen wie "unabhängig davon, was ich gegessen habe".... warum wird da nicht auch "von dem" verwendet?

Comment: Also ich sehe alle genannten Beispielsätze korrekt, allerdings können eventuell abweichende Bedeutungen entstehen, je nachdem, welche Variante man verwendet (siehe Beispiel von EM1 im Kommentar zur Frage). *Korrekt* sind aber alle Varianten.

Comment: Wenn man die Sätze unabhängig von ihrer Bedeutung betrachtet, sind sie korrekt. Der Ersteller der Frage bezieht sich aber (so wie ich ihn verstanden habe) auf eine bestimmte Bedeutung der Sätze, und auf diese bezogen sind sie nicht korrekt.

Comment: Welche bestimmte Bedeutung meinst du denn? Ich kann entsprechendes nicht aus der Fragestellung herauslesen...

Comment: Ich denke, dass Variante a) und b) jeweils die gleiche Bedeutung haben sollten. Variante a) ist ja nur korrekt (wenn ich das richtig verstanden habe), wenn sich das Relativpronomen "was" auf den ersten Teil des Satzes bezieht, und nicht das Pronominaladverb auf den zweiten Teil des Satzes. Das wäre also eine Abweichung von der Bedeutung der Variante b).