# Abgrenzung zwischen "was" als Relativ- und als Fragepronomen

Tags: grammar, pronoun, terminology

In [einer anderen Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/24857/kann-ein-relativsatz-an-ein-pronominaladverb-angeschlossen-werden) ging es kürzlich darum, ob sich an ein Pronominaladverb (davon, darauf, dafür) ein Relativsatz anschließen kann. 
Daraus ergab sich schließlich für mich diese Frage:

Was kann sowohl als Frage- als auch als Relativpronomen verwendet werden.

> 1.) Ich will wissen, was du essen willst.
>   2.) Das, was du gesagt hast, ist irrelevant.

In Satz 1 haben wir es offensichtlich mit einem Fragepronomen zu tun, das "was" in Satz 2 ist ein Relativpronomen. 
Doch es ist für mich nicht immer so klar.

> 3) Das hängt davon ab, was du willst.

Man kann den "was"-Teil gegen einen "wo"-Teil austauschen. Das spricht für Fragepronomen. Man kann aber auch statt "davon" "von dem" sagen. Das spräche dann für ein Relativpronomen. 
Noch ein Beispiel:

> 4.) Ich erinnere mich daran, was du gesagt hast.
>   4a.) Ich erinnere mich daran, wo du es gesagt hast. (Fragepronomen).
>   4b.) Ich erinnere mich an das, was du gesagt hast. (Relativpronomen)

Welche Wortart ist "was" in 3 und vor allem 4? Ein Relativpronomen oder ein Fragepronomen? Beides?
Meine eigentliche Frage ist:

- Kann man "was" als Relativpronomen klar, eindeutig und rein mechanisch (ohne Kontext) gegen "was" als Fragepronomen abgrenzen? Wenn ja, wie?
- Wenn nein, ist es überhaupt möglich, sinnvolle Regeln zu formulieren, die NUR auf den Gebrauch als Relativpronomen eingehen, ohne gleichzeitig eigentlich richtige Verwendungen als Fragepronomen auszuschließen?

Comment: Entspricht 4b nicht:  _4b.) Ich erinnere mich an **etwas**, **das** du gesagt hast. (Relativpronomen)_?

Comment: @Iris... streng genommen nicht. "An das" beinhaltet das definite "das". Es weist klar auf eine spezifische Sache, und nur auf diese. "an etwas" hat das indefinite "etwas". Die Person hat vieles gesagt, und an eine Sache davon erinnere ich mich, aber "etwas" selbst zeigt nicht darauf, sondern nur auf den "Haufen" des Gesagten.

Comment: stimmt, da verändert sich die Bedeutung. Dann stattdessen: _4b.) Ich erinnere mich an die Sache, die du gesagt hast. (Relativpronomen)?_  oder auch _4b.) Ich erinnere mich das, das du gesagt hast. (Relativpronomen)?_ (auch wenn zweiteres komisch klingt)

Comment: @iris... ja, das mit "Sache" funktioniert. Die andere Version nicht, da "das, das" nicht idiomatisch/(?grammatisch?) ist. Man sagt "das, was".

Comment: Hi Emanuel, irgendwie habe ich deine Frage nicht so gut verstanden. Ich nehme an, du fragst, ob das "was" als Relativpronomen nie mit dem "was" als Fragepronomen verwechselt werden kann. Wenn ja, dann kann ich das (zumindest als Nichtmuttersprachler) erklären. Man kann immer feststellen, ob das "was" der einen oder anderen Art ist. Als Relativpronomen muss das "was" immer direkt vor Alles, Nichts, dem "definite" Das, Etwas, oder einem Superlativ stehen, oder wenn nicht sich ganz in der Nähe befinden (zum Beispiel könnte ein infinitiv oder trennbarer Verbteil dazwischen stehen).

Comment: @Ledda... hast du da eine Quelle für? Ausserdem: nach der Logik ist dann "Ich erinnere mich daran, was du gesagt hast" kein Relativsatz. RIchtig?

Comment: Ich hätte wirklich erwähnen sollen, dass ich das nur aus meiner Sicht erkläre, so wie ich es mir beigebracht habe. In dem Beispiel sage ich ja, wenn es um ein Fragepronomen geht, und man möchte, dass es nach einer Präposition steht, muss man die Präposition in ein "da-wort" verwandeln.  Aber ich sehe was du meinst, und denke mal darüber nach, um eine Ergänzung zu diesen "Regeln", die ich mir ausgedacht habe, zu finden.

Comment: Ich habe gerade gemerkt, man kann den Was-Satz gegen einen Wo- Wenn- oder sogar Warum-Satz austauschen usw. Dann muss es sich sicherlich um keinen Relativsatz handeln, oder?

Comment: @Ledda... das ist genau der Punkt. "Das hängt davon ab, was/wo"... Fragepronomen. "Das hängt von dem ab, was..." Relativsatz. Beides ist möglich.

Answer (score 2):

Derart absolute Aussagen sind in der Linguistik selten möglich. In Wirklichkeit überlagern sich oft alle möglichen Effekte. Aufgabe der Grammatiker ist es dann, eine möglichst einfache Terminologie zu finden, die den tatsächlichen Gebrauch der Sprache möglichst genau beschreibt.

Relativpronomen sind oft auch gleichzeitig Fragepronomen, aus denen sie ursprünglich entstanden sind:

> 1) Ich will wissen: Was willst du essen?
>
> 2) Was hast du gesagt? Das ist irrelevant.
>
> 3) Was willst du? Davon hängt das ab.
>
> 4) Was hast du gesagt? Daran erinnere ich mich.
>
> 4a) Wo hast du es gesagt? Daran erinnere ich mich.
>
> 4b) Was hast du gesagt? An das erinnere ich mich.

Neben der Zeichensetzung besteht der Unterschied zu den ursprünglichen Beispielen nur in der Wortreihenfolge, und die war in früheren Stadien deutlich anders als heute und ganz früher (im Althochdeutschen) auch viel variabler. Aber auch im Frühneuhochdeutschen konnte man das meist noch nicht am Satzbau allein unterscheiden. Frühneuhochdeutsche Texte sind voll von Konstruktionen, die irgendwo zwischen zwei vollen Sätzen und einem Satz mit Nebensatz schweben.

Die Grammatik als ein System von absoluten Regeln bezieht ihre Legimitation ausschließlich daraus, dass sie den tatsächlichen Sprachgebrauch der beabsichtigten Gruppe von Sprachbenutzern (meistens angestrebt: die besten Autoren) hinreichend genau approximiert. Die Diskussion darüber, ob *was* im Einzelfall (eher) als Relativpronomen oder (eher) als Fragepronomen verwendet wird, ist eigentlich nur für die Autoren von Grammatiken sinnvoll, die daran arbeiten, die Sprache mit möglichst wenig Grundbegriffen möglichst genau zu beschreiben. Die können sich z.B. fragen, ob wir den Begriff des Relativpronomens wirklich brauchen. Kommen wir auch mit der Aussage aus, dass ein Relativsatz durch ein Frage- oder Demonstrativpronomen angeschlossen wird?

Zu den Unterscheidungen, die eine Grammatik treffen kann aber nicht zwingend muss, gehört auch die mir bisher nicht geläufige zwischen Relativ*pronomen* und (den neuen) Relativ*adverbien*, zwischen Frage*pronomen* und Frage*adverbien*. (Zu meiner Schulzeit war sie noch gar nicht üblich. Inzwischen ist sie mir öfters für das Englische und Französische begegnet. Jetzt sehe ich sie zum ersten Mal auch fürs Deutsche.) Wikipedia sagt zu den Relativadverbien, dass sie meistens formgleich mit Frageadverbien sind und es außer der (wohl semantisch motivierten) leicht eingeschränkten Verwendbarkeit von *wann* in Relativsätzen kaum einen Unterschied gibt. Es ist also denkbar, dass die jetzt übliche Unterscheidung von ...pronomen und ...adverbien letztlich dazu führen wird, dass man die Kategorien Relativadverb und Frageadverb zusammenfassen wird. Für das Relativ- und Fragepronomen *was* ist das natürlich nur insoweit relevant, als es zeigt, dass diese Kategorien nicht als naturgegeben und absolut interpretiert werden sollten.

Comment: Also sind die Antworten auf meine Fragen "nein" und "nein"?

Comment: Wie aus meiner Antwort klar geworden sein sollte, bin ich kein Experte für feine Punkte der konventionellen deutschen Grammatik. Deshalb bin ich nicht wirklich qualifiziert, um die Fragen mit klarem ja oder nein zu beantworten. Statt dessen sollte meine Sicht auf die Frage klar geworden sein: Die Frage ist ungefähr so sinnvoll wie die, ob man eine klare, mechanisch überprüfbare Unterscheidung zwischen Stuhl und Sessel treffen kann. Wenn man sie streng genug interpretiert, ist die Antwort auf alle derartigen Fragen immer nein.

Comment: Die Frage ist insofern sinnvoll, als sie bei der Beantwortung von Fragen wie "Kann nach einem Pronominaladverb ein Relativsatz folgen?" eine immens große Rolle spielt. Eine Frage, die hier schon gestellt wurde, und die auch bei Canoo beantwortet wird. Ich bin in diesem Fall wirklich an harten Fakten aus der Sprachwissenschaft interessiert. Trotzdem danke für die Antwort.

Answer (score 1):

> Kann man "was" als Relativpronomen klar, eindeutig und rein mechanisch
>   (ohne Kontext) gegen "was" als Fragepronomen abgrenzen? Wenn ja, wie?

Ja: Wenn man das "was" durch ein "das" ersetzen kann, ist es ein Relativpronomen.

> 2.) Das, was du gesagt hast, ist irrelevant.

Wird zu:

> 2.) Das, das du gesagt hast, ist irrelevant.

(Auch wenn es manchmal (wie hier beispielsweise) nicht so schön klingt.)
Bei 4b.) geht das demzufolge auch und klingt meiner Meinung nach sogar noch nach einigermaßen normalem Sprachgebrauch, während ich Sätze mit "Das, das du gesagt hast,..." noch nie von Anderen im normalen Sprachgebrauch gehört hab.

Comment: Wäre *welches* als Ersatz etwas schöner? Das, welches du gesagt hast? (Eventuell auch *dasjenige, welches*)